# how to make a non-ide specific java [ee/se] project

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, netbeans

At work one our guys is making a neat webpage for our QC team. He uses Eclipse (the EE version) We use Subversion for all of our programming projects. I checkout that project and decide to gander around the code for a minute or two just to see how it is going. I tried to open the project in my Eclipse (which was just SE version) and although it opened I couldn't really do much with it. Not only that but it was missing dependencies on JSF, and the MS JDBC library. I was getting super aggravated that I can't just open this project like I can in Visual Studio by double clicking on a solution file. If there are missing libraries and references I can easily tell what they are and go get them.

Now that story brings me to my question. Is there a way to put a java project (be it java se, java ee, or some web variation such as JSF) in subversion so that my coworker 1 can check it out and edit it in eclipose, coworker 2 and check it out and use intelliJ, and me get it and use Netbeans.

I've read a few things about Ant build scripts, and Maven but not being familiar with them I'm not sure that this is the fix that I need or want. If it is, then how would I go about switching his current project over to use said technology so that we can all easily edit and deploy this project?

Comment: Maven is pretty much the universally accepted answer.  How to set it up is the subject of large amounts of high quality documentation and probably beyond the scope of a single SO answer :)

Comment: ok, I wasn't sure if Maven was still a supported thing or not. I know that may seem silly, but for instance if you poke around on source forge you'll see projects using CSV. So I just wanted to also make sure that I was using a current solution

Comment: (Maven vs ANT vs IDE specific project files) and then (CVS vs SVN vs git vs etc) is kind of an orthogonal conversation.

Comment: true.. so would maven work for "all" java project types?

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/scm/scms-overview.html :)

Comment: Don't use common sense on me :P Thank you for the link I will start reading up now